# Converting polygon into single or all points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, geometry-conversion

I want to convert polygons into points using QGIS.

I know how it's done in ArcGIS Desktop.

How can I implement it using QGIS?

Comment: Do you mean convert the polygon borders into points or just reduce it to a point (get centroids)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do the ["Centroids"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#centroids) in QGIS using:

```
Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroids
```

Comment: Aragon, i didn't make it! i have 2 polygon and after using the tool i got only 2 point in the center of the polygon. i want point in the perimeter of the polygons.how do i do it with qgis?

Comment: Check gene answer below.

Answer (score 25):

You can ["Extract Vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices) in QGIS using:

```
Vector > Geometry Tools > Extract Vertices
```

There is also a tool called ["Extract specific vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-specific-vertices)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decide on your own point spacing, you can use the Sextante Toolbox with SAGA functionality activated (you'll need to install SAGA - http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html - and specify the installation path in sextante).

Use the ["Polygons to Lines"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.4/shapes_lines_0.html) geoalgoritm followed by the ["Lines to Points"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/shapes_points_5.html) one.  You can create a model in sextante that combines these into one step as well.

*Note:* you have to make sure you install the right version of SAGA - I think its 2.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Export polygon ;ayer  to SHP
Open with CloudCompare
Edit -->polyline-->sample points
save resilt vertices as csv
.
Import with QGIS (add layer--> delimited text layer)

Answer (score -3):

If you want to convert polygon to point using QGIS. Then use
Vector > Analysis Tools > Mean Coordinate.

Comment: Pay attention to that this algorithm computes a point layer with the center of mass of geometries in an input layer.