# Export polygon to points (vertices)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

This is the first time that I have worked with geospatial data and QGIS, so please be kind.

I was given a shape file that contains house districts for the state of FL.  [This link provides instructions](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/tableau-polygons-arcgis-shapefiles) (for ArcMap users) to import the house districts into Tableau, which is my goal.

I was able to generate a file that contains the district, and coordinates, but I need the order column, and am not sure how to do this using QGIS (assumedly using an add-in).

```
"shapeid","x","y"
"0","-87.634896","30.866261"
"0","-87.634871","30.866344"
"0","-87.634851","30.866536"
```

The format that I am looking for is ...

```
"shapeid","x","y","order"
"0","-87.634896","30.866261","1"
"0","-87.634871","30.866344","2"
"0","-87.634851","30.866536","3"
```

Comment: check out this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24442/how-do-i-convert-a-polygon-into-a-point